# Truffle will not compile my contract

Tags: truffle, blockchain

please i have a problem in my project truffle does not compile my contract , and also i dont know what to do with this error in the picture ? [image]

Comment: Could you share your entire code, so we might copy it and go through it ourselves? It is easier to find a way to solve your issue that way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.